# How to store minimal state for an Android Service WITHOUT touching storage

Tags: android, service, state

I need a way to save a small amount of state (basically just a 32-bit integer) that will survive across invocations of my IntentService.

I can't use SharedPreferences because it uses flash and this is inappropriate for my application.  I don't need this value to persist across reboots, anyway as it is more of a temporary value to let me know what to do the next time the service runs.  The only other alternative seems to be to make my service run all the time, which I would like to avoid.

edit: One idea I have come up with is to request different intents based on which state I am in.  For example, if I have 5 different states, I can have 5 different intents, and have AlarmManager return the one corresponding to the state I am in when my IntentService is done with its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplish by scheduling a PendingIntent with the AlarmManager with Intent extras containing the state to save.  If the information is needed, call getBroadcast() to get the intent, then cancel the alarm and call PendingIntent.send() it to oneself immediately to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

use an sqlite db. you can configure your table to have only one entry at a time.

Comment: won't the db be stored on flash or the external SD?  this is what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: nope, it comes with your application so it is stored in your application's reserved memory.

Comment: also if you don't mind me correcting, SharedPreferences doesn't use flash or external SD. You won't even have access to external memory unless you give your application the permission to do so.

Comment: This line from the documentation for SharedPreferences makes me believe they are: "the preference values remain in a consistent state and control when they are committed to storage."

Comment: anyway, the answer is no, it doesn't touch the external storage in any way. as i've mentioned, you need to give your app the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to write anything in sdcard. and by the way, you're referring to SharedPreferences.Editor in your quote. 
"Modifications to the preferences must go through an {@link Editor} object
 * to ensure the preference values remain in a consistent state and control
 * when they are committed to storage."

Comment: Whether you use SQLite or SharedPreferences, unless your device has  non-flash storage it's going to use flash. Just because it's not external storage/an SD card doesn't mean it's not flash. Most Android devices use flash for their internal storage. Only a very few use hard disks with magnetic platters.